# How can i close a sidebar in angular 8 based on window size on load?

Tags: html, angular

How can i keep the sidebar closed if i load the page on window with width less than 850 px.

I tried this code, but it only works on when i resize the window.

```
    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerWidth < 850) {
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
    if (event.target.innerWidth > 850) {
      this.sidenav.open();
    }
  }
```

and tried this as well but it doesn't work as well..

```
    constructor(){ this.width = window.innerWidth;}

    ngOnInit() {
    if(this.width < 850){
      console.log(this.width + " is");
      this.sidenav.close();
    } 
   }
```

Is there anyway to keep the sidebar closed on page load on window size condition..

Comment: which css framework do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ngafterviewinit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) instead of `ngOnInit` like

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
// your code to hide side nav
}
```